# Edit Button will Populate in FormArray Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get the list which contain `{dr: "DR2022000046" ,invoice: "SI09887"}` and populate it to the `formarray`. the problem is it did't populate it to my `formArray` Once i use the this.form.get('ItemRec').patchValue(this.IData)?

// Here is the form that i created.

```
this.form= this.fb.group({
      transactionNumber:['',Validators.required],
      transactionStatus:['', Validators.required],
      ItemRec: this.fb.array([this.CreateItemRec()])
    })
   
CreateItemRec():FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({  
          dr: ['', Validators.required],
          invoice:['', Validators.required],
        })
    
    }

get ItemRec(): FormArray {
      return <FormArray>this.receivedPropertyForm.get('ItemRec') as FormArray;
    }
```

//here what i do once i click the button and populate it.

```
this.sub = this.router.paramMap.subscribe(
        params => {
      const id = +params.get('Id');
        this.getListId(id);
        console.log(params)
      });
      
 getListId(id: number):void{
    this.micro.getAllList(id)
    .subscribe({
      next: (Details:DTO) => this.editData(Details),

      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    })
   }
   editData(Details:DTO): void{
    
    this.iData = Details;
    console.log(Details);
    
    this.form.patchValue({
      transactionNumber:this.iData.propertyTransactionGroup.transactionNumber,
      transactionStatus:this.iData.propertyTransactionGroup.transactionStatus
    });
   this.form.get('ItemRec').patchValue(this.iData)// this won't work got error value.forEach is not a function at FormArray.patchValue
   }
```

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear what you are trying to obtain and what's the actual issue

Comment: a few suggestions not directly related to your issue, but which are really bothering in terms of naming conventions: ItemRec ->should be renamed to something more suggestive and should follow the camelCase pattern. CreateItemRec -> should be camel case. dr is not suggestive at all, it should be a lot more descriptive. the Details parameter of the arrow function and the 'editData' function should be camel case, so "details". If you do care about having clean code, please make these updates and also edit the code here after that. 'DTO' should probably be something like "DetailsDTO"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495204/angular-formarray-patchvalue-error-typeerror-value-foreach-is-not-a-function

Comment: @vaira we got a common but i dont have [] things in my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.iData` should be an array but it seems you are passing an object, that is why the error says it could not use `foreach` on `this.iData`

```
this.form.get('ItemRec').patchValue([this.iData]) // basically pass an array in patchValue
```

example of correct input

```
 this.form.get('ItemRec')
.patchValue([ {dr: 'A', invoice: ''} , {dr: 'A', invoice: ''}])
```